# Transactions in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I now know that in MySQL there is a [list](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/implicit-commit.html) of statements that cause implicit commit, like `CREATE`, `ALTER`, etc., and I want to know if there is such a thing in SQLite.

In other words I want to know whether, for example, `CREATE TABLE` and some other constructs cause autocommit and therefore cannot be rolled back?

I tested it myself and it seems to me that SQLite behaves like MySQL, but I'm not sure of that and I want to have some reference to the documentation that lists all such commands (I could not find one).

Besides, I want to know if it is possible to tweak some SQLite parameters to prevent it form autocommitting `CREATE` and other statements.

We all know for example, that it is impossible to rename a field in SQLite or to change its type (using one command), but in order to do that we have to create a new table with needed schema and import data to this table. Obviously, such an operation should be implemented in a single transaction, but how if in fact `CREATE TABLE` and `DROP TABLE` commands cause autocommit?

Counter-example:

```py
import sqlite3

cnx = sqlite3.connect("test.db")
cursor = cnx.cursor()
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE funky (attr_1_ integer)")
cnx.rollback()
```

As you can see I do not use any special pragma and I do not even commit explicitly, but when I run it and then go to sqlite3 prompt, I see that the table `funky` still exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the exception of some special PRAGMAs ([foreign_keys](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_foreign_keys), [journal_mode](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_journal_mode)), *all* SQL commands are [fully transactional](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html):

> No changes can be made to the database except within a transaction.

SQLite will use autocommits only if you aren't using explicit transactions:

> Any command that changes the database (basically, any SQL command other than SELECT) will automatically start a transaction if one is not already in effect. Automatically started transactions are committed when the last query finishes.

---

To be able to roll back a CREATE TABLE, you must

- use an explicit transaction, and
- (only in Python) disable Python's [autocommit mode](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3-controlling-transactions):

```py
import sqlite3

cnx = sqlite3.connect("test.db")
cnx.isolation_level = None
cursor = cnx.cursor()
cursor.execute("BEGIN")
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE funky (attr_1_ integer)")
cursor.execute("ROLLBACK")
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could elaborate a little bit on this. The fact is, my own tests without using any special pragmas show, that for example `CREATE TABLE` autocommits. And I guess there are another commands that also cause implicit commit. So, if you could support your idea with verifiable examples, that would be absolutely great.

Comment: This question is about SQLite, not about [Python's misguided attempt to be clever](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3-controlling-transactions).

Comment: Why all commands are transactional, If I can see with a nacked eye, that they are not? Why it is a "misguided attempt to be clever"? And so forth and so on. If you could provide any argument or any trusted reference to a particular part of some documentation, that would be absolutely great.

Comment: Your question is *not* about Python, so I can answer only about what SQLite itself does. If you want to ask about the behaviour of a specific bit if code, show that code.

Comment: Although Jacobian eventually accepted the answer, there are still gaps in the explanation.  The answer says to "**disable** Python's autocommit mode" by setting `isolation_level = None`, yet the very page linked to says "If you **want** autocommit mode, then set isolation_level to None" (where I interpret "want" to mean "enable", not "disable").  They contradict each other.  What does "misguided" mean if the answer doesn't even seem to agree with the Python docs.  Despite the example code which may work as desired, the explanations still don't mesh.

Comment: If I understand correctly, then the answer should say something like "disable Python's *automatic transaction isolation implementation* and allow sqlite's default implicit transaction handling".  [This page](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/get_autocommit.html) explains that sqlite is always in autocommit except during an explicit transaction started with BEGIN (and I will add SAVEPOINT).  I am guessing that Python's implementation with isolation_level != None means that Python wraps transactions with explicit BEGIN TRANSACTION statements.  Is that correct?